# How would you sort a django mptt tree?

Tags: django, django-mptt

Imagine that I have an mptt tree of objects and their population like:

Animal, 60

- aardvark, 30
- bobcat, 20
- chipmunk, 10

Vegetable, 6

- apple, 1
- beet, 2
- cauliflower, 3

Mineral 0

How would you sort the above by population on each sublevel?  I want to get to:

Animal, 60

- aardvark, 30
- bobcat, 20
- chipmunk, 10

Vegetable, 6

- cauliflower, 3
- beet, 2
- apple, 1

Mineral 0

I am building off of mptt in django.

Comment: A link to the topic in question would be useful http://code.google.com/p/django-mptt/

Answer (score 2):

I've just solved a similar issue. You can use an `order_by`, but not simply by the field you want to sort by:

```
MyModel.tree.all().order_by('tree_id', 'level', 'your_sort_field')
```

Comment: Won't work if the depth level becomes 1 <

Answer (score 0):

Try to add it in the [models.py](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#id3) Meta Class.

Or on a subsidiary [QuerySet](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#order-by-fields)

Answer (score 0):

Should an `order_by` simply work?

```
YourModel.tree.filter(your=stuff).order_by('order')
```

Comment: There is no `order` field.